# Limit of how many nw-js instances can we run?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node-webkit, chrome-remote-debugging

I am having an issue that I cannot run more then 115 instances of nw-js. Hardware is not the problem, but it looks like there is some restriction somewhere.

Does anyone know why I cannot run more then 115 instances?

Comment: Memory? May be to try run not full instace, but just open new window? OS?

Comment: Open new window? Linux, 32 cores, 64gb or ram, ssd drive.

Comment: Oppening new windows done, but then you have the problem of not being able to control browser windows with chrome-remote-interface through its remote-debug port (all windows are running on the same port). Is it possible to open new chromium window and assign it new port?